# RSA encryption using Microsoft Excel

Tags: encryption, excel, cryptography, rsa, vba

Is there any ready to use implementation of RSA encryption algorithm for Excel( just encrypt a plain text using given public key, nothing else ) ? Or I need to implement it from the beginning ? I Google but found nothing useful.

Any useful links is welcome.

**UPDATE:**

I need a non-commercial library.

Comment: I, too, would like such an example (similar to Excel), so I can follow along with a video, such as [this cool explanation](https://youtu.be/M7kEpw1tn50) which has two "3"s unfortunately or a superior one. [This one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjL2aa7-c_NAhUsw4MKHfYaCqcQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.csc.gatech.edu%2F~copeland%2F6612%2Ftools%2FRSA.xls&usg=AFQjCNEcpxFe57eYbI6teiWaZlVLj2BkDA&sig2=ECQfTZJZZXW7OYLcQbQ5Cw&bvm=bv.125801520,d.eWE) falls apart at 2^32 limit for Excel mod(x,n).