# VBA: How can I generate a signature with RS256 based on private key in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, jwt, rsa, sha256

I am trying to generate a JSON Web Token (JWT) in VBA. I need it to be signed with RS256. So far, I managed to create the base64 encoded header and payload. They are both working fine.

Now I am stuck on signing the JWT header+payload with RS256. I cannot find a default VBA class or function, that provides RSA-SHA256 working with private key for encryption. In the official Microsoft documentation I only found methods using public key for encryption: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netcore-3.1. Additionally, I am not even sure if the Components are COM visible.

My search results in Stackoverflow also either want public key and not private key for encryption, or have not been solved yet:

[How to generate signature with RSA-SHA1 and private key through VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696129)
[RSA encryption using Microsoft Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500280)

I am aware, that I may use extensions that would provide RSA with private key or even a full implementation of JWT generation. However, due to security issues and monetary aspects, I either cannot or do not want to use such extensions. This means, I want to solve the problem with default VBA and the accessible Microsoft Framework Components.

```
' Generate RSA keypair (later, private key must be imported from PEM-File)
Set csp = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider")
privateKey = csp.ExportParameters(True)
publicKey = csp.ExportParameters(False)

' Create test-string for signing
Dim dataString As String
dataString = "Data"

' Convert test-string to bytes
Dim dataByte() As Byte
dataByte = StrConv(dataString, vbFromUnicode)

' Create instance of SHA256 (NOT WORKING!)
'   Run-time error '429':
'   ActiveX component can't create object
Set SHA256 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider")

' Create instance of RSA algorithm
Set RSAalg = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider")
' Load private key
RSAalg.ImportParameters (privateKey)

' Sign data (propably not working - tried with SHA1)
'   Run-time error '5':
'   Invalid procedure call or argument
Dim signedData() As Byte
signedData = RSAalg.signData(dataByte(), SHA256)

Debug.Print StrConv(signedData, vbUnicode)
```

Can anyone provide a solution or point me to a possible direction?

Answer (score 1):

signdata() is error you need use signhash()

encryt with rsa sha256 sha1 md5 vbscript vba classic asp

https://github.com/ekede/WTS-Classic-ASP-MVC-Framework/blob/master/inc/class/crypt/rsa.asp